# Warning message:: NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r

A had stored lat and longs of polygons in  mysql database. Now i am trying to retrieve those using R.

```
A <- list(Latitudes1,Longitudes1)
polygon(A[[1]])
```

where latitudes1 and latitudes2 are retrieved coordinates from mysql database.

[image]

when I run polygon(A[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ8N9.png)]) function, A warning message generates-
Warning message:
In xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : NAs introduced by coercion.
can somebody tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: Your `A` is stil raw, you will have to parse it to get a numeric vector of latitudes/longitudes. Please provide a reproducible example (no figures if not necessary, please).